# Professors and Liberal Arts Colleges

Tags: publications, professorship, teaching

In general, do professors work at liberal arts colleges because they do not want to have to face the pressure of writing a lot of research papers? Instead they want their evaluations to be skewed towards their teaching quality?

Comment: Question sounds overly provocative. Teaching creates pressure, too. There are several deadlines every week (each lecture). Also, some people prefer teaching over research. I don't think they are trying to skew their evaluation, rather they are doing what they want to do.

Comment: I agree with what Dave Clarke and Pete Clark said. There's plenty of pressure in a liberal arts job. However, there is often more pressure related to being a great teacher, and less pressure related to winning a grant. There's certainly plenty of pressure to publish. As a math professor at a small liberal arts college, I have published over 30 papers in the past ten years, but probably could have gotten tenure with only 6 (good) papers. I certainly didn't choose the job to avoid research pressure. I chose it because I love teaching and research both.

Answer (score 11):

You're not expressing the question in the most flattering way, but yes: most academic jobs are a mix of research and teaching (and also service / administration), and there is a lot of variation in the importance placed on each from job to job.  Some people are more interested in one than the other, and the faculty at liberal arts colleges have signed up for a job in which more emphasis is placed on teaching and student contact than a, well, a research university.

At a good liberal arts college faculty are still expected to be research active -- it's just that they spend more hours per week on teaching than their colleagues at a more research-oriented institution.  Someone who felt like writing research papers was pressure that they didn't want to face would probably be more comfortable at something like a four-year, junior, or community college, in which in most cases the research expectations are really nominal.

Comment: But a professor isn't prohibited from publishing a lot of papers even if he/she works at an LAC?

Comment: Prohibited in what sense?

Comment: Like is there a limit for example like 20 papers per year a professor can publish at a LAC?

Comment: No, there are no publication limits in any academic job (!!).

Comment: I wish there were limits :). "You shall NOT publish more than two papers a year"  - that would be so awesome.